# Spring 4.3.10 controller throws Http 400 (Bad Request) whereas Spring 3.1.1 works just fine

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We have a legacy code running Spring 3.1.1. The controller looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/model/save", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, headers = "Accept=application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO save(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonProperty,  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
     MyObject myObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonProperty, MyObject.class);
     // save myObject here
     ... 
}
```

Right now, this controller works as expected.

I'm in the process of upgrading Spring to 4.3.10. As part of this task, I have all the latest Spring jars and corresponding jackson jars in the classpath.
But this time, I get Http 400 (Bad Request) error.

Just looking at the legacy code, I realized that we are reading JsonNode as a request body and then mapping it to the model to be saved. So I changed the code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/model/save", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, headers = "Accept=application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO save(@RequestBody MyObject myObject,  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // save myObject here
    ... 
}
```

This change works just perfect.
I have 2 questions:

1. Is the legacy code following proper coding standards?
2. Why is the legacy code (Spring 3.1.1) does not work in latest Spring (4.3.10)?

Comment: You should be getting a stack trace on the server. Post it. (You might have to turn up the log level on `DispatcherServlet`.)

Comment: Also, GET requests don't have a body. It makes no sense to map this method to GET.

Comment: Hi @Chrylis, thanks for useful tip. I saw an exception in the catalina.out. It's about DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver and some other info, which, I think, will lead me to investigate the issue in proper direction. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet, you are right. Though the controller says GET (or POST) request, the UI is sending POST. And it doesn't make any sense to have it GET. I have removed it.

Comment: Here is the exception:
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@51237a92; line: 1, column: 1]

The question still remains, how was this working in Spring 3.1.1?

Comment: Are you sure the `JsonNode` is the same type (no imports changed)?

Comment: Yes @chrylis, no source code change, only Spring and Jackson libraries were upgraded.